# Batch: File Not Found

Tags: batch-file, winrar

`start %~dp0\files\engine.hta`

When I tried to open the file in a batch file in a RAR file, it does not work, but when I try to open in a folder, it works correctly. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the RAR file is a container file for compressed data. RAR file is not a structure like a folder. It is not a part of the file system. So no batch file is working inside a RAR file.